# Custom attributes in magento repeating

Tags: magento

When i have create a custom attribute in magento from magento product catalog while adding it is repeating the custom attribute multiple times also when i am trying to delete the custom attribute it is not deleting please can any body help?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't contain any code, it would be better suited to the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?